# Access sdcard download folder while targetsdkversion is 30

Tags: android, storage

i can read a file from sdcard with targetsdkversion 29 by using the following code

```
String filepath = "/storage/9E5C-E122/Download/maps.dat";
```

But with targetsdkversion 30 it gives following error.

```
java.io.filenotfoundexception open failed eacces (permission denied)
```

Searched alot and i cant find a solution, i just want to read the file from the Download folder in SDcard.

My code which reads the sdcard name, ExternalPath1 return the card name.

```
private static int getMountedSDCardCount(Context context) {
        ExternalPath1 = null;
        ExternalPath2 = null;
        int readyCount = 0;
        StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager) context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
        if (storageManager == null)
            return 0;
        Method method;
        Object obj;
        try {
            method = storageManager.getClass().getMethod("getVolumePaths", (Class[]) null);
            obj = method.invoke(storageManager, (Object[]) null);

            String[] paths = (String[]) obj;
            if (paths == null)
                return 0;

            method = storageManager.getClass().getMethod("getVolumeState", new Class[] { String.class });
            for (String path : paths) {
                obj = method.invoke(storageManager, new Object[] { path });
                if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(obj)) {
                    readyCount++;
                    if (2 == readyCount) {
                        ExternalPath1 = path;
                    }
                    if (3 == readyCount) {
                        ExternalPath2 = path;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
            if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                readyCount = 1;
            }
            Log.d("Test", ex.getMessage());
            return readyCount;
        }

        Log.d("Test", "mounted sdcard number: " + readyCount);
        return readyCount;
    }
```

Comment: Which app did put that file there? Android version of used device? How did you determine that full path?

Comment: My app is an navigation app and i used the sdcard to store the offline maps which is sqlite ddb file. i copied the db files into the download folder through pc, i determine the full path using a custom class.

Comment: I just want read the file, which location is easy to access so that i can copy my files there. i thought that the download folder will be easy to access.

Comment: Apps on Android 11 cannot read/write/delete files of other apps. if you used a pc these files dont belong to your app. Your app cannot even find them normally. So what does your custom class do to be able to find them?

Comment: So which location can i use on my sdcard so i can read it?

Comment: That is no answer. How does your custom class find them was the question.

Comment: The class is just to read the sd card name 9E5C-E122, submitted the app with manage storage permission and go rejected. They asked me to use Media Store API. From which location i can read the file from sd card?

Comment: Well show the code with which you determine the sdcard name. After that tell how you determined full path "/storage/9E5C-E122/Download/maps.dat". Put all code in your post. Write a decent post to begin with. Im asking already for 24 hours and still dont know how you determined full path.

Comment: sorry, updated the question with the code.

Comment: That determines only sd card name. Not full path of a file. How do you determine that file?

Comment: i copied that file through PC at Download folder.

Comment: Ok. But how does your app determine file name AND ful path? I asked that two days ago. How difficult can it be to answer such simple questions? Two days ago!